# Run SQL script from R with variables defined in R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have an SQL script which I need to run using R Studio. However, my SQL script has one variable that is defined in my R environment. I am using `dbGetQuery`; however, I do not know (and I didn't find a solution) how to pass these variables.

```
library(readr)    
library(DBI)    
library(odbc)    
library(RODBC)

#create conection (fake one here)
con <- odbcConnect(...)

dt = Sys.Date()   

df = dbGetQuery(.con, statement = read_file('Query.sql'))
```

The file 'Query.sql' makes reference to `dt`. How do I make the file recognize my variable `dt`?

Comment: Take a look at `glue_sql`: https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html.

Comment: FYI, a few things: (1) you define `con` and use `.con` (dot), probably a typo. (2) You appear to be using `con` created from `RODBC` but trying to use it in a `DBI` function. I have not used `RODBC`, but are you certain that is appropriate and functional? (3) In reality, you need `RODBC` (with `odbcConnect` and `sqlQuery` but *no bound parameter support*), or you need `DBI` and `odbc` (with `dbConnect` and `dbGetQuery`, with bound parameter support). You do not *need* both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options, but my preferred is ["bound parameters"](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

If, for instance, your `'Query.sql'` looks something like

```
select ...
from MyTable
where CreatedDateTime > ?
```

The `?` is a place-holder for a binding.

Then you can do

```r
con <- dbConnect(...) # from DBI
df = dbGetQuery(con, statement = read_file('Query.sql'), params = list(dt))
```

With more parameters, add more `?`s and more objects to the `list`, as in

```r
qry <- "select ... where a > ? and b < ?"
newdat <- dbGetQuery(con, qry, params = list(var1, var2))
```

If you need a SQL `IN` clause, it gets a little dicey, since it doesn't bind things precisely like we want.

```r
candidate_values <- c(2020, 1997, 1996, 1901)
qry <- paste("select ... where a > ? and b in (", paste(rep("?", length(candidate_values)), collapse=","), ")")
qry
# [1] "select ... where a > ? and b in ( ?,?,?,? )"
df <- dbGetQuery(con, qry, params = c(list(avar), as.list(candidate_values)))
```

Comment: is there a way to adapt this solution if I have two variables?

Comment: Yes, read the docs. Long story short: `qry <- "select ... where a > ? and b < ?"`, then `dbGetQuery(con, qry, params = list(var1, var2))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is for readers in search of a solution. An alternative to the accepted answer is to use [`glue::glue_sql()`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html), and the [sqlhelper package](https://majerr.github.io/sqlhelper/) supports both methods, see [Interpolation](https://majerr.github.io/sqlhelper/articles/execution.html#interpolation) and [Binding](https://majerr.github.io/sqlhelper/articles/execution.html#binding). Assuming your `dt` variable is a string, your `query.SQL` file might look like:

```sql
SELECT {`dt`} FROM some_table
```

and you could execute it with:

```r
sqlhelper::run_files("query.SQL")
```

(disclosure: I wrote sqlhelper)